# $4\times4$ magic square magic number possibilities?

Tags: combinatorics, magic-square

How can I find all the different possibilities for the sum of rows/columns/diagonals for a $4\times4$ magic square? I am not sure how to proceed, except by brute force, which is entirely inelegant.

I should mention that I am looking at a $4\times 4$ magic square with symbols from $0$ to $15$ inclusive.

Comment: Do you really mean that you want the possibilities for the *sum* of the rows? If a magic square contains the integers 1–16, then there is only one possibility, namely $\frac14(1+\ldots+16) = 34$; if the square is allowed to contain any positive integers, then any sum is possible. And do you mean a *magic* square, or a *Latin* square? They are not the same thing.

Comment: See the edit on the question. As I said I could not find he magic square tag.

Comment: Also how might we go about proving that 34 is the only possibility?

Comment: The numbers from 0 to 15 add up to 120. In a magic square, all the rows have the same sum. The four row sums must add up to that 120, so each must be 30. As noted, a Latin square is an entirely different thing.

Comment: @DanielleHuang Count the same thing two different ways: if the row sum is $r$, then the sum of all the entries in the square must be the sum of row 1, row 2, row 3, and row 4: $r+r+r+r=4r$.  Meanwhile, if the square contains each of the numbers from 0 through 15 (or 1 through 16) exactly once, then the sum of all the entries is...

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 possible sum :
[What are the possible sums of an $n \times n$ magic square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992336/what-are-the-possible-sums-of-an-n-times-n-magic-square)
That sum would be 30 in a 4x4 magic square with numbers 0-15

EX:

| 0 | 7 |11|12|

|13|10| 6 | 1 |

|14| 9 | 5 | 2 |

| 3 | 4 | 8 |15|

Comment: The link points to a different problem that is not relevant to this one.