# Reverse engineering a math magic trick involving matrices.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, magic-square

This problem was brought up by my mother from a corporate party along with a question on how that worked.

There was a showman who asked to tell him a number from $10$ to $99$ (If i'm not mistaken). The number $83$ was named after which he took a piece of paper and quickly put down a matrix (note he did that fast):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 11 & 63 & 1\\
62 & 2 & 7 & 12\\ 
3 & 65 & 9 & 6 \\
10 & 5 & 4 & 64
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If you take a closer look every row, column and diagonal has the sum of $83$. Moreover consider the corners of the matrix also have the sum of $83$. For example:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color\red{8} & \color\red{11} & 63 & 1\\
\color\red{62} & \color\red{2} & 7 & 12\\ 
3 & 65 & 9 & 6 \\
10 & 5 & 4 & 64
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Also the central square is $83$ in sum as well:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 11 & 63 & 1\\
62 & \color\red{2} & \color\red{7} & 12\\ 
3 & \color\red{65} & \color\red{9} & 6 \\
10 & 5 & 4 & 64
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Clearly numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12$ are filled in in a circular manner. And then consequent $62, 63, 64, 65$ are as well. I'm not very familial with linear algebra so my question is:

> What was that rule he used to build it? Can we construct a matrix with the same properties given a random number in some range? Is it possible to build a similar one but for $5\times 5$, $6\times 6$ or $N\times N$ matrix?

Comment: What kind of show was that?

Comment: @Icv i've never seen this show, so  i do not know. It was at a corporate party for the co-workers. The only thing I got was a piece of paper with numbers written on it.

Comment: It’s hard to imagine a less geeky show :-)

Comment: This feels more like recreational mathematics than linear algebra.

Comment: Reminds me of a paper I read before about constructing magic squares. Have a look at this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263329901_Challenging_Magic_Squares_for_Magicians

Comment: To show that you can get *any* sum on the rows, columns, and two main diagonals for *any* $N \times N$ magic square ($N \ge 4$), see my Answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992336/what-are-the-possible-sums-of-an-n-times-n-magic-square/1992998#1992998

Comment: Are only five $2 \times 2$ blocks ($4$ corners plus center) being considered?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo those blocks were considered during the trick. But you may discover [more areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:4x4_magic_square_hierarchy.svg) with the sum of $83$. And yes all of them are $2\times 2$, at least for square segments.

Comment: I ask because in the Numberphile video linked to below they consider $4$ additional $2 \times 2$ (contiguous) blocks. I just want to know for sure how many constraints there are.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, well I believe the constraints were up to the showman, but he could also use areas other than the square ones. For example if you find numbers $3, 10, 6, 64$ in that matrix, the sum is $83$ as well but it's not a $2\times 2$ segment, the same refers to $62, 3, 12, 6$

Comment: @Icv In 2002 there was a candidate (Alfred Weber) in the *German* TV show ["Wetten dass..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetten,_dass..%3F) who claimed he can fill in a 4x4 magic square in real time with any given number for the rows and columns. He succeeded and was awarded the "Wettkönig" title, i.e. his performance was voted by the audience as the most stunning one, and he received a monetary reward. Only a day later, German papers already wrote about the triviality of the trick and how the showmaster "Thomas Gottschalk" was fooled by this candidate.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is all based on the amazing matrix $$\pmatrix{8&11&14&1\\13&2&7&12\\3&16&9&6\\10&5&4&15}$$
Note that this works for $34$. For $34+n$ you just replace $13,14,15,16$ with $13+n,14+n,15+n,16+n$. I do not know what the showman's backup plan for numbers below $34$ is.

EDIT: There is a [Numberphile video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQxCnmhqZko) on this exact trick.

Comment: I also believe it was not 10, but rather some larger two digit number

Comment: Thanks for sharing a link to the video! Also it looks like magic does not exist after all :)

Comment: It's possible that his backup plan was to subtract some number from those four.

Comment: @JarredAllen Or perhaps use a smaller matrix? Subtract all numbers from 100, effectively inverting the trick? No clue, but there are possibilities indeed.

Answer (score 16):

He did not write down 'a matrix'. He wrote down a [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).

There are various algorithms for constructing them, the easiest to do mentally is to start with a generic starter matrix you memoize:

```
 A  1 12  7
11  8  B  2
 5 10  3  C
 4  D  6  9
```

And solve for A, B, C, D for your target number. With some practice you can do this super fast.

Comment: Of course it is a matrix as well.

Comment: @JannikPitt Of course. I just remarked on it as if someone arriving by private helicopter to do grocery shopping is described as "arriving by vehicle".

Answer (score 6):

Observe that the numbers in the sixties lie on different rows, different columns and different quadrants. If you increase them simultaneously, all the twelve sums increase by the same amount.

In the pure magic square (numbers $1$ to $16$), the sum is $34$, hence if suffices to add $83-34=49$ to these four elements.

It would be more logical to request a sum in the range $[34,83]$ so that all elements are at most two-digit naturals.

For stronger mystification, you can split the required increment in two or more and adjust on the other possible groups.